# How can I hide or protect login username and passwords?

Tags: python, security, python-3.x, authentication, passwords

I wrote this simple python(3.4.2) program, however I don't know how can I make username and password secure, so that no one can see it?

---

```
from tkinter import *

w=Tk()
w.title ("Login")

def login ():
    x=e1.get()
    y=e2.get()
    if x=='hamed' and y=='1371516':
        messagebox.showinfo (title='Login',message='Login successfuly')
        w.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo (title='Error',message='username or password is wrong!')

l1=Label (w,text='Username',fg='red')
l1.grid(row=1,column=1)
l2=Label (w,text='Password',fg='red')
l2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5)

e1=Entry (w,width=20)
e1.grid(row=1,column=2)
e2=Entry (w,width=20,show="*")
e2.grid(row=2,column=2)

b1=Button (w,text='Ok',width=10,command=login)
b1.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W,ipadx=20)
b2=Button (w,text='Exit',width=10,command=w.destroy)
b2.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=W,ipadx=20)

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please, specify what do you mean by "make them secure" and "so that no one can see it". Do you want to hide them from the screen (start(*) representation of passwords) or store them in a secure manner, or send them to someone securely, etc.. Giving a specific example may help to better illustrate your question.

Comment: Check https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/383461/tkinter-password-entry-form if you want to hide on screen.

Comment: At this code you can see password(1371516)! If someone can see code (anyway),he can see password too! Should i use hash.if yes how?

Comment: Please update your question with that information and the corresponding example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid storing the password in plaintext in the code or anywhere else (e.g database, file, etc.) use hash and salt. You will hash the concatenated password and salt and store like: hashtype$hash$salt

```
hashtype = hash(plaintext|salt)
```

Then to check the password, you will concatenate the input with the corresponding salt, hash it, and compare to the stored hashtype.

My advice is to avoid implementing your own hash algorithm and use a verified one like `SHA`.

For example code you can look at [Django's Source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py) and the corresponding [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/). Also, searching here for password hashing in Python will give you some good answers with examples.

Comment: don't use a simple salted-hash (like salted-sha), but rather something good from the "passlib" python package. modern algorithms use many rounds and/or other means to make them intentionally expensive to compute, to make brute-forcing the hashes harder.

Comment: @ThomasWaldmann First, there is no simple and complicated salted-hash. There is one type of salted hash and "simple" and "complicated" hashes. Second, SHA is a modern algorithm. And the recommended "something good" from passlib is SHA-256.

Comment: well, maybe read the passlib docs. What I meant with "simple" is a single-round hash (with or without a salt), like salted-sha256. that is definitely NOT recommended for password storage and the docs are quite clear about that.

Comment: Then you should have said simple hash, not simple salted-hash. I read the passlib documentation and ``SHA-256`` is one of their recommended hashes. Also number of rounds is not all the define the strength of a hash.

Comment: @ThomasWaldmann following your link comment, I would add that there is a difference between theoretical and practical attacks.

Comment: if someone copies and bruteforces one of your hashes, it does not matter whether you used a salt or not (as the salt is known). aside from that, I think I have made my point, feel free to ignore that advice on your systems.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'secure'? For hiding password from screen during input you can use getpass:

```
import getpass
credentials = {}
credentials['user'] = raw_input("Login: ")
credentials['password'] = getpass.getpass()
```